# Doing the equivalent of find . -name 'myfile*.csv' using windows and Java

Tags: java, regex, selenium, windows-7

I am using Selenium and Chrome.  One page I access downloads a file automatically but I can not be sure which directory it is downloading to.  Generally it is c:\users\\Downloads\ but I can't be assured that is where it is.  The name will be MyFiles_*.csv (this is windows notation.  The regex would be MyFiles_[0-9]+.csv or something similar.

So I would like to do something line the unix find C: -name 'MyFiles_.*.csv' to find what directory this file is in.  I found the below code example but it appears to look only in the current directory and not the subdirectories:

```
File f = new File("C:\\");
    File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith("MyFiles") && name.endsWith(".csv");
        }
    });

    for (File f1 : matchingFiles) {
        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to check all subdirectories too (and return the full name with the full path)?

Another question as an aside.  Sometimes when I search for a file in windows it finds it in a directory but also in a directory called something like "Recent Files".  I guess if the algorithm returns > 1 directory I can eliminate any with "Recent" in it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You could "simply" use recursion. Or from Java 7 on, the [FileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) API.

Answer (score 0):

Solution suggested by [Mena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2353911/mena):

> You could "simply" use recursion. Or from Java 7 on, the [FileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) API.